# How to update on conflict of another update in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi consider that I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE customer_fruits (
 customer_id varchar(10),
 fruit_name varchar(50),
 PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, fruit_name)
);
```

Then I inserted these two rows

```
insert into customer_fruits values('cust_01', 'apple'),('cust_01', 'APPLE');
```

Now I want all my fruit names to be lower case.

```
update customer_fruits set fruit_name = LOWER(fruit_name);
```

but the above command returns an error because cust_01,apple already exists:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "customer_fruits_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (customer_id, fruit_name)=(cust_01, apple) already exists.
```

So I want to set the fruit_name to null when this problem exists so what I thought of is:

```
update customer_fruits set fruit_name = LOWER(fruit_name) on conflict(customer_id, fruit_name) do update set fruit_name = null;
```

but I got an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 1: ...ustomer_fruits set fruit_name = LOWER(fruit_name) on conflic...
```

Comment: @VaoTsun I am using version 9.5.6

Comment: on coflict is upsert  implementation with insert, not update - I just noticed you try to use it with update

Comment: @VaoTsun yes but I want something similar to use it in case of update

Answer (score 0):

```
update customer_fruits c
    set fruit_name = case when dupvalue=1 then lower(fruit_name) else null end
    from (select c2.*, row_number() over (partition by LOWER(fruit_name) order by LOWER(fruit_name)) as dupvalue
          from customer_fruits c2
         ) c2
    where c2.LOWER(fruit_name) = c.LOWER(fruit_name)
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting